# Touchpad does not work when I hold down a key on the keyboard

Tags: touchpad, dell-inspiron

I have recently received a DELL inspiron 15 laptop with windows 8 on it. I have tried out Minecraft on it but when I hold down the keys to move, the touchpad stops working. What do I do?

Comment: You should consider buying a mouse. Playing games with touchpad isn't fun ;)

Answer (score 3):

Ensure the touchpad isn't set to turn off while typing.

Many touchpads have this option to prevent accidental touchpad hits, causing unexpected mouse movements, while typing.